# ApacheDS suddenly stopped connection

Tags: apache, ldap

I've setup ApacheDS on my windows7 machine. It was working fine but suddenly it says connection refused. 
Server is up but when trying to connect it gives below error. Please help

Error while opening connection
 - Cannot connect on the server: Connection timed out: no further information
org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.exception.InvalidConnectionException: Cannot connect on the server: Connection timed out: no further information
    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.connect(LdapNetworkConnection.java:564)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$1.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:227)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1174)

Answer (score 0):

> It says connection refused.

No it doesn't. It says 'connection timed out'. It's not the same thing.

You have a connectivity problem or a firewall problem between the client and the server.

Comment: I had disabled firewall but did not help. I'm trying to open connection within Apache DS LDAP browser.

Comment: Can you ping the server host from the client?